How to stop monitoring process in Flask/Python?
in my project I have a USB monitor running, but I see it interfere with other functions, so I want to start/stop it when necessary. In my code the start function is ok, but the stop one no, I can't get it stop.
Here's the code:
#lots of import stuff#

# USB Monitoring Process (global variables to manage lifecycle, 
# there are many due to the experiments I made trying to solve the issue)
usb_process = None
running = False
usb_monitor_thread = None
usb_monitor_started = False

def device_event_monitor(action, device):
    if device.subsystem == 'usb':
        if action == 'add' and device.device_type == 'usb_device':
            # my code does stuff and get some info from the connected device
            # especially gets some values to generate an hash 
            # to insert in a sql database 
            device_hash = hash_object.hexdigest()
            if device_hash in hash_list:
                cursor.execute(
                    "UPDATE devices SET connection_time = ? WHERE hash = ?",
                    (start_time, device_hash),
                )
            else:
            # This is the part I can't get working: I want to stop monitor and
            # start a device registration process through a webpage, but
            # I see no message, the monitor does not stop, the page is not rendered
                stop_usb_monitor()
                print(f"STOP MONITOR!!")
                with app.app_context():
                    return render_template("new_device.html")

def monitor_usb():
    global running
    context = pyudev.Context()
    monitor = pyudev.Monitor.from_netlink(context)
    monitor.filter_by('usb')
    monitor.enable_receiving()
    observer = pyudev.MonitorObserver(monitor, device_event_monitor)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while running:  
            time.sleep(0.1)  
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\nMonitor manually stopped.")
    finally:
        observer.stop()
        print("Monitor USB stopped.")

def start_usb_monitor():
    global running, usb_monitor_thread
    if running:
        print("Already running!")
        return
    running = True
    usb_monitor_thread = threading.Thread(target=monitor_usb, daemon=True)
    usb_monitor_thread.start()
    print("\nMonitor started!")

def stop_usb_monitor():
    global running, usb_monitor_thread
    if not running:
        print("Monitor not running!")
        return
    running = False  
    if usb_monitor_thread:
        usb_monitor_thread.join()  # Aspetta la terminazione del thread
        print("Monitor USB stopped!")

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/start', methods=['POST'])
def start():
    start_usb_monitor()
    return render_template("table.html")

@app.route("/new_device", methods=["POST"])
def new_device():
    device_name = request.form.get("owner_name")
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Start Flask app
    app.run(debug=True)`

Please sorry if my code is messed, I am a beginner and I tried a lot of variables to start/stop the monitor. One thing I found is that JavaScript in my html pages interfered in many ways, so I keep the pages in plain html and get some better result (mainly to control the starting of the monitoring process, at first I put it to start automatically).

This
MRE
works for me: https://pastebin.com/raw/Xh3USaep

Sorry I don't understand the logic: should I stop the monitor by running stop_usb_monitor (like in my code) or by setting running false?

I mean that the MRE is working so try to produce the smallest code that's not working.

I have the impression that you are thinking too complicated.
The pyudev.MonitorObserver is already a thread that can be started and stopped. This means that it is not necessary to use another thread to outsource the monitoring.
The following example shows you one way of starting and stopping monitoring via a website. All filtered events are reported to the site via a socket and displayed. Depending on the requirements, you should adapt and revise the code to suit the circumstances.
If you want to stop the observer from within the event handler, you should use MonitorObserver.send_stop().
'''
Install the requirements:
% pip install pyudev flask flask-socketio
'''

from  flask import (
    Flask, 
    render_template_string, 
)
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from threading import Lock
import pyudev

class MyObserver:
    def __init__(self):
        self.context = pyudev.Context()
        self.monitor = pyudev.Monitor.from_netlink(self.context)
        self.monitor.filter_by('usb')
        self.monitor.enable_receiving()
        self.observer = None
        self.thread_lock = Lock()
    
    def log_event(self, action, device):
        data = {
            'action': action, 
            'device_path': device.get('DEVPATH'), 
            'device_name': device.get('DEVNAME'), 
            'device_vendor': device.get('ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE'),
        }
        sio.emit('event', data)
    
    def start(self):
        with self.thread_lock:
            if self.observer is None:
                self.observer = pyudev.MonitorObserver(self.monitor, self.log_event)
                self.observer.start()

    def stop(self):
        with self.thread_lock:
            if self.observer is not None:
                self.observer.stop()
                self.observer = None

app = Flask(__name__)
sio = SocketIO(app)
observer = MyObserver()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template_string('''
        <form name="start">
            <button type="submit">Start</button>
        </form>
        <form name="stop">
            <button type="submit">Stop</button>
        </form>
        <div id="device-infos"></div>
        <script 
            src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.8.1/socket.io.min.js" 
            integrity="sha384-mkQ3/7FUtcGyoppY6bz/PORYoGqOl7/aSUMn2ymDOJcapfS6PHqxhRTMh1RR0Q6+" 
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            (function() {
                const handleEvent = (data) => {
                    const devInfoEl = document.createElement('div');
                    devInfoEl.innerHTML = `
                        <table width="100%" border="1">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Action</td>
                                    <td>Path</td>
                                    <td>Name</td>
                                    <td>Vendor</td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>${data.action}</td>
                                    <td>${data.device_path}</td>
                                    <td>${data.device_name}</td>
                                    <td>${data.device_vendor}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    `;
                    const devInfosEl = document.getElementById('device-infos');
                    devInfosEl.append(devInfoEl);
                };

                const handleStart = (event) => {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    fetch('/start', { method: 'post' });
                };

                const handleStop = (event) => {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    fetch('/stop', { method: 'post' });
                };
                
                sock = io();
                sock.on('event', handleEvent);

                document.querySelector('form[name="start"]').addEventListener('submit', handleStart);
                document.querySelector('form[name="stop"]').addEventListener('submit', handleStop);
            })();
        </script>
    ''')

@app.post('/start')
def start():
    observer.start()
    return ''

@app.post('/stop')
def stop():
    observer.stop()
    return ''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sio.run(app)

